# Catching errors generated from the phone vs. the webservice

Tags: windows-phone-7, soap, error-handling

Is there a way to differentiate errors from a webservice and errors from the phone (no connectivity/timeout and so on)?

I'd like to show the user the errors that is generated from our webservice, but I don't really care to show them from the phone. I'd rather just show them "An error has occurred, please try again" or something similar.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try accessing the source in a try catch block that would generate an exception

in my WCF Service I try and access my DB and if it fails then my WCF throws an Exception which is fine but the phone doesnt know what to do with it until I access the e.Result(); and the error is thrown,

put a try and catch block around that and you get your exception caught

```
void webclient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
           e.Result(); 
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Sorry There was an error while trying to connect to the server", "Please Try Again", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        }
```